# Cursor appears before field loads on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, focus

My web app includes a login button which dynamically adds a form to the DOM tree (with a username and password field) and sets the focus to the username field.  It all works fine, however the cursor appears fractionally before the field has appeared on screen which I don't like.  This being mobile Safari I can't put a setTimeOut on the focus command (the focus command must be in the function called by the users click, calling it from another function causes Safari to ignore it).  I can't use a nasty delay as that also delays the loading of the form and the cursor still pops up before the field loads.

Anyone got any (preferably simple) ideas?